# Navigation state from hidden to shown is lag

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Hi I have two ViewController.

One is ViewController others is TableViewController.

And Both are embedded navigationController and TabController.

First ViewController's navigationController is always hidden.

Second TableViewController's navigationController is always shown.

My problem is when I tap to switch Second TableView then It's navigation Controller shown looks lag.

And Second TableView has no line of code about the navigationBarHidden options.

I wish to switch smoothly..but It looks lag when NavigationController.

Here is my code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

//calling function to load posts
loadPosts()



}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}


override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had trying to setNavigationBarHidden. It seems smoothly but It also have delay...